# In ReactJS, Displaying Snackbar(mui) with mobx observer did not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I'm new to reactjs, and I've just started using state management tool Mobx.

I'd like to show Snackbar using mobx store.

The logic is simple.

When the error was occured, it was added to mobx's observable alert list.

And, the observer component catched that change, and rebuild component.

Here is my code.

```js
// BaseAlert.ts
interface BaseAlert {
  message: string;
  display: boolean;
}

export interface Success extends BaseAlert {
  kind: 'success';
}

export interface Info extends BaseAlert {
  kind: 'info';
}

export interface Warn extends BaseAlert {
  kind: 'warn';
}

export interface Error extends BaseAlert {
  kind: 'error';
}

export type Alert = Success | Info | Warn | Error;

export const alert = (message: string, kind: Alert['kind']): Alert =>
  ({
    message,
    kind,
    display: true,
  } as Alert);
```

```js
// Alerts.ts
import {just, Maybe, nothing} from 'maybeasy';
import {action, computed, observable} from 'mobx';
import {Alert} from "../base/BaseAlert";

class AlertsStore {
  @observable
  alerts: Alert[] = [];

  @computed
  get current(): Maybe<Alert> {
    return this.alerts.length === 0 ? nothing() : just(this.alerts[0]);
  }

  @action
  hide = () => {
    if (this.alerts.length > 0) {
      this.alerts[0].display = false;
    }
  };

  @action
  process = () => {
    this.alerts = this.alerts.slice(1);
  };

  @action
  push = (alert: Alert) => {
    this.hide();
    this.alerts.push({...alert, display: true});
  };
}

const alertsStore = new AlertsStore();
export default alertsStore;
```

```js
// ObservableAlert.tsx
import React from 'react';
import alertsStore from "../../hook/AlertsStore";
import {Snackbar} from "@mui/material";
import {observer} from "mobx-react";

@observer
export class Alerts extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return alertsStore.current.cata({
      Just: alert => (
        <Snackbar
          anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
          open={alert.display}
          onClose={alertsStore.hide}
          onDragExit={alertsStore.process}
          message={alert.message}
          autoHideDuration={1000}
        />
      ),
      Nothing: () => <></>,
    });
  }
}
```

And, I added the **ObservableAlert** component just below the App Component.

```js
// App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<HomeView/>}>home</Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginView/>}>login</Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Alerts/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I input username and password in textfield and click the login button, this function is called to push alert into the alertsStore.

```js
  async login(username: string, password: string) {
    await this.baseEventHandle({
      action: async () => {
        await this.loginUserUseCase.invoke(username, password);
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        alertsStore.push(alert(error, 'error'));
      }
    })
  }
```

I checked above function's **onError** inner function was worked and new Alerts Instance was added to **AlertsStore**'s Alert list.

But, the snackbar did not show at the browser.

Could you tell me what is the problem of my code??

Comment: What version of mobx do you use? Could you maybe make a quick repro on https://codesandbox.io/?